# AngularJS - Add and remove class to element when div is within view (scrolling).

Tags: jquery, angularjs, web

First of all, here is what I'm trying to achieve: http://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/JKpKjX

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section__img">
            <div class="section__img__inner" style=
            "background-image: url(http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/iPad-mini-3-silver-side-by-side.png);">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section__body">
            <div class="section__text">
                <h2>Section title</h2>
                <p>Sed dapibus ornare risus vel vehicula. Nunc elit lacus,
                lacinia vel molestie et, lacinia non augue. Aenean quis iaculis
                velit. Sed aliquet semper metus quis egestas. Nullam lorem
                turpis, euismod nec feugiat at, venenatis quis odio. Aenean
                tellus libero, rutrum in mauris in, suscipit aliquam lacus.
                Proin ac viverra risus. Vivamus ullamcorper, massa id congue
                sagittis, erat ipsum aliquet tellus, nec sollicitudin erat
                risus vitae nisl.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section__img">
            <div class="section__img__inner" style=
            "background-image: url(http://wpuploads.appadvice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/ipad-c4a63aad52bb1d69495bc2100e5f2026.png);">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section__body">
            <div class="section__text">
                <h2>Section title</h2>
                <p>Sed dapibus ornare risus vel vehicula. Nunc elit lacus,
                lacinia vel molestie et, lacinia non augue. Aenean quis iaculis
                velit. Sed aliquet semper metus quis egestas. Nullam lorem
                turpis, euismod nec feugiat at, venenatis quis odio. Aenean
                tellus libero, rutrum in mauris in, suscipit aliquam lacus.
                Proin ac viverra risus. Vivamus ullamcorper, massa id congue
                sagittis, erat ipsum aliquet tellus, nec sollicitudin erat
                risus vitae nisl.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section__img">
            <div class="section__img__inner" style=
            "background-image: url(http://www.consult-pro.com/img/dental-videos-ipad-app.png);">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section__body">
            <div class="section__text">
                <h2>Section title</h2>
                <p>Sed dapibus ornare risus vel vehicula. Nunc elit lacus,
                lacinia vel molestie et, lacinia non augue. Aenean quis iaculis
                velit. Sed aliquet semper metus quis egestas. Nullam lorem
                turpis, euismod nec feugiat at, venenatis quis odio. Aenean
                tellus libero, rutrum in mauris in, suscipit aliquam lacus.
                Proin ac viverra risus. Vivamus ullamcorper, massa id congue
                sagittis, erat ipsum aliquet tellus, nec sollicitudin erat
                risus vitae nisl.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    line-height: 1.618;
}

.background {
    background-color: #ffcd03;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

.section {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

    > * {
        width: 50%;
    }

    &__img {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;

        &__inner {
            height: 100vh;
            position: fixed;
            left: 5%;
            width: 40%;
            top: 0;
            mix-blend-mode: multiply;
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }
    }

    &__body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    &__text {
        padding: 5vw;
    }
}


.section__img__inner {
    filter: blur(30px);
    opacity: 0;
    background-position: 50% 40%;
    transition: filter .6s ease, opacity .6s ease, background-position 0.8s ease;
}

.section.active .section__img__inner {
    opacity: 1;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    filter: blur(0);
}

h2 {
    font-size: 3vw;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  // selectors
  var $window = $(window),
      $body = $('body'),
      $panel = $('.section');

  var scroll = $window.scrollTop();

  $panel.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    // if position is within range of this panel.
    // So position of (position of top of div <= scroll position) && (position of bottom of div > scroll position).
    // Remember we set the scroll to 33% earlier in scroll var.
    if ($this.position().top <= scroll && $this.position().top + $this.height() > scroll) {

      // Remove all classes on body with color-
      $body.removeClass(function (index, css) {
        return (css.match (/(^|\s)color-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
      });

            $('.section').removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');

    }
  });    

}).scroll();
```

Every section of the html has an image associated with it. I'm trying to make an image dynamically appear on the left side of the screen as I scroll through the html body on the right side. However, the code example above is using jQuery and my app is an angular app so I'm trying to adapt it to angular style code. Please let me know if my title is unclear or doesn't describe what I'm trying to accomplish.

(UPDATED) This is my work in progress attempt so far: http://jsfiddle.net/nxhpg7rs/

Had to hardcode the $window.pageYOffset instead of doing it how the jQuery example at the top does it.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I got it!! Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sn4qj6Lr/

Here is the .js for my solution:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive("scroll", function($window) {
    var result = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element(document.querySelector('#first')).addClass('active'); //Loads the first image by default.
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            var scrollHeight = this.pageYOffset + (this.innerHeight / 3);
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var el = angular.element(document.querySelector('#' + result[i].id));
                if (el.prop('offsetTop') <= scrollHeight && el.prop('offsetTop') + el.prop('offsetHeight') > scrollHeight) {
                    el.parent().children().removeClass('active');
                    el.addClass('active');
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

I did need to add an id to each section in the html to be able to identify the element related to it and use .prop(), .addClass(), .removeClass(), etc. Not sure if there's a workaround where each "section" doesn't need to have it's own unique id. If there is, any suggestions would still be much appreciated!